# How much energy would it take a person to make an object weighing 10 tons move 10 m/s with an inch punch?

Tags: physics, martial-arts

We assume that the object will withstand the impact. Air resistance and friction force are neglected.

Comment: Are we also to assume that the person throwing the punch has infinite inertia, because if a normal mass person punches 10 tons away at 10 m/s. they will go flying in the opposite direction at a speed of 110 m/s.

Comment: This doesn't look like a worldbuilding question. Maybe it belongs on the Physics forum?

Comment: @Nosajimiki - particularly if friction is neglected.

Comment: Also, I'd point out that "withstand" is a word that can mean a lot of things.  Unless it's a perfectly elastic material, some energy would be expected to be lost to deformation.

Comment: This feels like a high school problem. No SO community does your homework for you.

Answer (score 5):

The length of the punch is irrelevant. It will take 1/2 * 10,000kg * (10m/s)^2 = 500,000 joules of energy.

Where the 1 inch becomes relevant is in calculating force and power. Imparting that much energy over a distance of one inch will require an average force of 19,685,039.4 Newtons, or the equivalent of approximately 2,000 tonnes of weight.

Comment: So around 120 kilocalories, that is, about six jelly babies.

Comment: @Showsni it always amazes me how 'dense' chemical energy is relative to thermal or kinetic energy

Comment: The human body is only 25% efficient at turning food into energy and ~45% of that energy is reinvested into liver, spleen, kidney, and heart functions to cleanse you of all the bad leftovers of your metabolic system which only leaves about 11.25% for your brain and muscles.  So, you would actually need to eat about 1100 kcal. of food to power this punch. (Wife: You went to McDonalds again?!  Him: It's okay, I punched a bad guy today.)